# Sorting Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data

I have some data with mixed of String and Integer like,

```
"003G"
"002P"
"001P"
"018P"
"002G"
"019P"
"001G"
"020P"
"012P"
"011P"
"012G"
"013P"
"007P"
"011G"
"010P"
"009P"
"008P"
"005P"
"006P"
"014P"
"007G"
"010G"
"009G"
"008G"
"015P"
"006G"
"005Ga"
"004P"
"016P"
"005G"
"004G"
"003P"
"017P"
```

Need output like :

```
"001P"
"002P"
"003P"
"004P"
"005P"
"006P"
"007P"
"008P"
"009P"
"010P"
"011P"
"012P"
"013P"
"014P"
"015P"
"016P"
"017P"
"018P"
"019P"
"020P"
"001G"
"002G"
"003G"
"004G"
"005G"
"005Ga"
"006G"
"007G"
"008G"
"009G"
"010G"
"011G"
"012G"
```

Same time Android done the sorting with `*[0-9,0P-9P,0G-9G]`

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "sorting CoreData", sorting the array retrieved from `CoreData`?

Comment: I have sort based on key :
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"referenceNo" ascending:YES]; 

output is like :
"001G"
"001P"
"002G"
"002P"
"003G"
"003P"
"004G"
"004P"
"005G"
"005Ga"
"005P"
"006G"
"006P"
"007G"
"007P"
"008G"
"008P"
"009G"
"009P"
"010G"
"010P"
"011G"
"011P"
"012G"
"012P"
"013P"
"014P"
"015P"
"016P"
"017P"
"018P"
"019P"
"020P"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a very unusual sorting order. You have to write custom descriptors using a `Comparator`

Two descriptors are needed.

1. Sort the fourth character descending

   ```
   let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "referenceNo", ascending: false) { (obj1, obj2)  -> ComparisonResult in
       let string1 = obj1 as! String
       let string2 = obj2 as! String
       let fourthChar1 = string1.index(string1.startIndex, offsetBy: 3)
       let fourthChar2 = string2.index(string2.startIndex, offsetBy: 3)
       return String(string1[fourthChar1]).compare(String(string2[fourthChar2]))
   }
   ```
2. Sort the first 3 characters ascending with `numeric` option and consider the `xxxxa` case

   ```
   let sortDescriptor2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "referenceNo", ascending: true) { (obj1, obj2)  -> ComparisonResult in
       let string1 = obj1 as! String
       let string2 = obj2 as! String
       let fourthChar1 = string1.index(string1.startIndex, offsetBy: 3)
       let fourthChar2 = string2.index(string2.startIndex, offsetBy: 3)
       let orderedResult = string1.substring(to: fourthChar1).compare(string2.substring(to: fourthChar2), options: .numeric)
       if orderedResult == .orderedSame {
           return string1.characters.count < string2.characters.count ? .orderedAscending : .orderedDescending
       } else {
           return orderedResult
       }
   }
   ```

Of course this assumes that the values are strings with always 4 characters and more in the ASCII range.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *keysArray;  // your strings
```

Put every strings into an array and use code below

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [keysArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Apple provides several selectors for alphabetic sorting:

```
compare:
caseInsensitiveCompare:
localizedCompare:
localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:
localizedStandardCompare:
```

Comment: It's seems not work for me, result after sorting just like normal in Swift. Does anyone have a successful in this way?

Comment: surely it will work for you. my be you giving wrong array @ovo

Comment: `print(nsTexts.sortedArray(using: #selector(NSString.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare(_:))))`, then result is `[001G, 001P, 002G, 002P, 003G, 003P, 004G, 004P ....`. so... it's not work.

Comment: Your result is correct man,... it is same as in dictinary.. for example sequence: aaa aba abb abc aca ada..

Comment: The result for the method is correct but not answer the question for Jinu.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NSFetchRequest to query core data, then go ahead and add sort descriptor on fetchRequest like below :

```
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"referenceNo" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
```